# What happens if you go away from the center in No Man's Sky?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I read in an interview with Hello Games that every player starts on the edge of the galaxy and there is a sort of "race" to the center where there is a surprise.

What is there if you go *away* from the center?

Comment: I don't think there's anything special. Once you hit the edge, there's probably just less planets that you can jump to. You definitely don't get any reward or prize (heck, you can argue you don't get a reward even for going to the center).

Comment: Supposedly, there is better stuff closer to the center, but getting to the center seems to be a huge disappointment. I'm sure your likelihood of finding already discovered systems further out is lower, though.

Comment: I'm actually curious to know if there is a boundary you can hit or if some how you will just see stars farther and farther apart from each other to a point where you can't warp to them.

Answer (score 3):

Getting to the center of the universe is one of three options for playing the game and exploring; the other two being following the Atlas Path or exploring freely.

Choosing to follow the Atlas Path or moving towards the center sets your path as you jump between systems to progress you along that path. If you choose instead to go in the opposite direction of the center, you're then just choosing the third option and exploring the universe freely.

So if you choose to go away from the center, nothing happens - you simple get to freely explore the universe.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. This answers about the different three paths. The OP wants to know what happens if you go away from the center, not about the different paths.

Comment: @JasonHeine Exactly, if you're not explicitly following one of the two set paths, then you're just creating your own path with the third option. Nothing happens beyond discovering new planets and everything they have to offer.

Comment: Right, but it still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @JasonHeine It answers the question by saying nothing happens by going away from the center, and explaining exactly why.

Comment: Well, supposedly, the quality of things you'd find on planets would be lower... So there is something

Comment: @Vemonus A number of players on Reddit have said the only obvious difference in finding more scarce and valuable resources is tied to the difficulty of the star system (I believe they're yellow, red, blue, and green). Very little has been confirmed from Hello Games, so both ideas are purely speculation.

Comment: @QuestionMarks hence the supposedly ;-)